# Is there any open-source and free to use software that can update all the third party software like node, java, adobe

Tags: windows, gratis, package-manager

Doing this by one by one is big pain, especially in the software where there is no built in option to update the software to the latest stable version, do you know any software that will do the job for me

Answer (score 2):

[Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) has the option to upgrade all: `choco upgrade all`.